# Py/Django: Set variables in template

Tags: python, django

I try to make a month calendar view with python/Django. 
Is it possible to set variables in {%  %}  segments?

I want to have it like this:

- January:
- 01.01.2016 test entry
- 06.01.2016 on other entry
- 25.01.2016 last Jan entry
- February:
- 03.02.2016 hello

The top month names are generated when a new month starts. 
Is something like this possible?

```
{% if entry.month == lastmonth %} 
// show month name
{% lastmonth = entry.month %}
```

And this in a for structure?

Comment: Can you explain how you are getting the data, and if you are looping through in some way? I've provided a generic answer on setting variables inside django templates, I'll update my answer if I get more information from you. Or someone else will be able to answer better.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `{% with %}` template tag to set variables inside templates. See here for details: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#with

In your case, you can do something like this:

```
{% for item in collection %}
    {% if item-satisfies-condition %}
        {% with variable=some-value %}
            stuffs...
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```